# Issue with using std::bind placeholder along with boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I've created a unit test using boost library test framework and encountered an issue with using std::bind placeholder along with the said library.

If I explicitly use `std::placeholders::` + _1, it works fine:

```
 std::bind(&TestFixture::concatStrings, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2)
```

But if I omit the `std::placeholders::` and directly use `_1`, it results to a compilation error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'std::string std::_Pmf_wrap<std::string (__thiscall TestFixture::* )(const std::string &,const std::string &),std::string,TestFixture,const std::string &,const std::string &>::operator ()(_Farg0 &,const std::string &,const std::string &) const' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'boost::arg<1>' to 'const std::string &' C:\APPS\msvs2013\VC\include\functional  1149    1   test
```

Using lambda, is the best solution I can think of:

```
[&](const std::string& x, const std::string& y){ return concatStrings(x, y); }
```

I just want to understand if using methods defined in std conflicts with boost library, such as the std::bind. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> If I explicitly use std::placeholders:: + _1, it works fine:

So if you use it correctly, and as documented, it works.

> But if I omit the std::placeholders:: and directly use _1, it results to a compilation error:

And if you use it incorrectly, it doesn't work.

> I just want to understand if using methods defined in std conflicts with boost library, such as the std::bind.

Yes, there's a naming conflict. There's not a conflict per se, but unfortunately Boost Bind historically put their placeholders into the global namespace.

It's perfectly possible to use Boost Bind `::_1`, Boost Phoenix, Boost Spirit `boost::spirit::qi::_1` and `std::bind` together, but yeah, you may have to qualify the placeholders. Alternatively, use your own aliases.

---

PS. It looks like in this case you should be able to use `std::mem_fn`. If you use lambdas _prefer not to use `[&]` as it's an unsafe habit. In your case you only needed to capture `[this]` or if you wanted, `[=]`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Using `_1` works fine with boost::bind. Though, if I'm going to explicitly use std::bind, I should use the `std::placeholders::_1`. Thanks for pointing out the capture in the lambda, I'll make it a habit of choosing my capture safely. :)